# How to edit tables and columns and rows for databases (psql) on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails 5 application running on Heroku.
I have been able to modify the database on my local environment (c9) using $psql commands.

[image: Image of local psql database table schema]

I removed users, articles, and comments on the $psql console

I ran rails db:migrate and no problems it removed locally.
I pushed the changes successfully to git with no problems.
I pushed the changes successfully to heroku with no problems.
I ran rails db:migrate on local environment with no problems.

When I ran rails db:migrate it says "users" column still exist on Heroku psql(production environment) db.

So to clarify:

I'm not really sure what way (or whats even the right way) to modify tables, their columns, and rows from a psql database that is on rails with heroku.
How do I properly remove rails psql database rows and columns after its already been deployed to an existing URL on Heroku?

Comment: So all you (should) have left is the `connects` table? Is there any data in it that you care about?

Answer (score 0):

Columns are edited and removed with Rails migrations: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method

With using migrations the columns will be removed on both the dev and production environment using `rake db:migrate`.

Rows you can delete in various ways, through the Rails application or in the Rails console using ActiveRecord, or another way of interfacing with the database.

---

Edited according to top comment below

Comment: Are you sure about the "If you delete them manually they will still exist in the schema after running migrations." part? Doing a `rake db:migrate` should regenerate `db/schema.rb` based on the structure of the database (after running any migrations) regardless of what the migrations say or do.

Comment: No I'm not sure, thanks for your comment. I wouldn't have expected that. So if you then ran `rake db:reset` the schema would then go back to reflecting the migrations? It seems a bad idea to me for the schema to not reflect the migrations, and I think that's what's causing the issue in the original post.

Comment: The `schema.rb` reflects what Rails thinks the database currently looks like, migrations are just temporary instructions on how to get from one database structure to another. If you `db:reset`, the database will be be rebuilt based on what `schema.rb` looks like, not what the migrations have to say. The OP's problem is that they changed the database schema by hand, ended up with a new `schema.rb`, and have no way to `db:migrate` their production system to the new schema because there are no migrations.

Comment: I see, that's good to know. I'll leave the answer here as I think it answers the question of how to edit and remove rows and columns from the db in general, despite not being able to fix the OP's particular problem.